# How to have array size depending on parameter in class using template

Tags: c++, templates, stdarray

I have a graph consisting of Q-tuples, where Q is either 3 or 6. The nodes in the graph are modeled as
`typedef std::array<int,3> NODE` or `typedef std::array<int,6> NODE` respectively. To be more flexible I used a template class

```
template <int Q>
class DARP
{
// some attributes
    int capacity = Q;
    typedef std::array<int,Q> NODE;
    NODE depot;
    void create_nodes();
};
```

However, the following implementation results in an error.

```
template <int Q>
void DARP<Q>::create_nodes()
{
    if (capacity == 3)
        depot = {0,0,0};
    else
        depot = {0,0,0,0,0,0};  
}
```

This can be fixed by

```
template <int Q>
void DARP<Q>::create_nodes()
{
    for (int i=0; i<Q; i++)
    {
        depot[i] = 0;
    }
}
```

but when I'd like to create more complicated nodes like `{0,1,4,8,9,10}` it would come in handy to be able to write it in this "short" form. Is there any way to handle this more elegantly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Constexpr If](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17) with template parameter `Q` as:

```
if constexpr (Q==3)
    depot = {0,0,0};
else
    depot = {0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

According to the condition value, the *statement-true* or *statement-false* will be discarded and then won't cause the error.

Before C++17, you can specify `create_nodes` as:

```
template <>
void DARP<3>::create_nodes()
{
    depot = {0,0,0};
}
template <>
void DARP<6>::create_nodes()
{
    depot = {0,0,0,0,0,0}; 
}
```